# Volcar datos en un fichero sin sobreescribirlo [Java]

Tags: java, string, archivo, print, filewriter

Estoy escribiendo un código en el que invoco un servicio web. La parte de la invocación y la recogida de los datos la tengo resuelta. Pero sin embargo, al ser unos datos analíticos, los quiero volcar en un fichero .csv. La cuestión es que en cada llamada abro el fichero .csv y lo sobreescribo, es decir, borro el contenido anterior y guardo el nuevo contenido. Lo que quiero hacer es abrir el fichero con el descriptor al final y añadir el contenido en vez de sobreescribirlo. Para la escritura utilizo PrintWriter y StringBuilder.
El código es algo así:

```
    JSONObject thisJson = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    JSONArray arrayJson = thisJson.getJSONArray("analytics");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("./src/TestResults/situmAnalytics.csv"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("device_id");
    sb.append("\t");
    sb.append("time_sec");
    sb.append("\t");
    sb.append("position_x");
    sb.append("\t");
    sb.append("position_y");
    sb.append('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject JSONobj = arrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("device_id"));
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("time_sec"));
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("position").replace("[" , "").replace("]", "").split(",")[0]);
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("position").replace("[" , "").replace("]", "").split(",")[1]);
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    pw.write(sb.toString());
    pw.close();
```

Como se puede ver comienzo añadiendo una cabecera al principio pero no quiero hacerlo cada vez que va a escribir en el fichero..¿como puedo saber si el fichero en el que voy a escribir es nuevo (añadir la cabecera) o ya existía? Y lo más importante, usando estas librerías de Java ¿puedo abrir el fichero con el descriptor al final o es mejor usar otras librerías?

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.. cualquier dato orientativo me será útil !

Comment: Mira esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210616/printwriter-append-method-not-appending

Comment: Gracias @David.. eso me lo ha solucionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo visto, el constructor de la clase PrintWrite no ofrece la posibilidad de abrir el descriptor del fichero al final. He consultado el enlace que me ha sugeriro @David en los comentarios y la alternativa que plantea funciona.
Para que se pueda ver la respuesta es StackOverflow en Español, comento el código modificado:

```
    JSONObject thisJson = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    JSONArray arrayJson = thisJson.getJSONArray("analytics");

    //Uso new FileOutputStream(new File("filePath"), true) --> El true indica que se abre al final
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("./src/TestResults/situmAnalytics.csv"), true));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (fileExist == 0) {
        sb.append("device_id");
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append("time_sec");
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append("position_x");
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append("position_y");
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject JSONobj = arrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("device_id"));
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("time_sec"));
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("position").replace("[" , "").replace("]", "").split(",")[0]);
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(JSONobj.getString("position").replace("[" , "").replace("]", "").split(",")[1]);
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    pw.write(sb.toString());
    pw.close();
```

También añado la comprobación de la cabecera en función de si el fichero ya existe o no.